# How do I pass HTML table inside mailto in anchor tag?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx, spfx-webparts, react

I am creating a web part in SharePoint Online using SPFx REACT framework and I want to open an email pop up with an HTML table in the body section of the email.

Currently, I am using mailto to open an email and I can see my HTML code in the body section of the email. Are there any ways in REACT/JavaScript/jQuery with which I can achieve this functionality?

Current code:

```
    let mailBody = `<table>
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
  </table>`;
    location.href = `mailto:myEmailID?subject=Hello&body=${mailBody}`;
```

Comment: Hi, does my below answer help you in any way? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to add HTML tables in email body as you are using `mailto` which does not support using HTML in email body.

> Section 2 of [RFC 2368](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368) says that the `body` field is supposed to be in `text/plain` format, so you can't do HTML.

**Source**:

1. [Is it possible to add an HTML link in the body of a MAILTO link [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247245/is-it-possible-to-add-an-html-link-in-the-body-of-a-mailto-link)
2. [mailto link with HTML body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-link-with-html-body)

---

You maybe able to add line breaks and other characters using ASCII code as shown in below article but you cannot add complete HTML table: [HTML email links code – How to add a subject, body text and other cool stuff](http://www.zaposphere.com/html-email-links-code/)

Comment: Is there any other way to open an email (outlook) on button click with a table in the body section?

Comment: Check if this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46699855/8624276